# Can you say "linduro" to refer to a man as a "lindura"?

Tags: traducción, género

Okay so I've been searching Spanish nicknames and if you refer to a girl, you can call her *lindura* which they say means cutie or beauty (depending on which site you're on).

Would the male version of it be *linduro*? Since they often do that in Spanish I thought so, but while searching I can't find anything that suggests so. They don't find anything and instead I get even more sites talking about lindura... Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You may use "guaperas". And since we are at it . . . In Rossini's opera  The Barber of Seville there is a guy named Lindoro, but Rossini was Italian.

Answer (score 8):

["Lindura"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NMmCYa4) is the abstract noun for the adjective "lindo" or "linda" and has therefore no masculine. Being an abstract noun, you can use it to refer to a man or a woman indistinctly.

In my country, we never use it. Instead, we use "preciosura" (the quality of being "precioso/preciosa") or "belleza" (the quality of being "bello/bella") or "hermosura" (the quality of being "hermoso/hermosa").

Such abstract nouns can be deemed to be used to mean that the person in question is, more than just beautiful, the embodiment of beauty.

Comment: Aw thank you so much!!  <3